# why is when fragment is hidden, onStop isn't called?

Tags: android

I attached bottom navigation to my app and call changeFragment. When I call changeFragment, for example, A fragment to B fragment, I expected to be called onStop at A fragment. However, Any lifecycle callback isn't called.. Why is happened?

THIS IS MY CODE..

```
private fun setBottomNavigation() {
    binding.bottomNavigation.run {
        setOnItemSelectedListener { menu ->
            when (menu.itemId) {
                R.id.navigation_menu_main ->
                    changeFragment(mainFragment, MainFragment.TAG, menu.itemId)
                R.id.navigation_menu_money ->
                    changeFragment(moneyFragment, MoneyFragment.TAG, menu.itemId)
                R.id.navigation_menu_life ->
                    changeFragment(lifeFragment, LifeFragment.TAG, menu.itemId)
                R.id.navigation_menu_food ->
                    changeFragment(foodFragment, FoodFragment.TAG, menu.itemId)
                R.id.navigation_menu_menu ->
                    changeFragment(menuFragment, MenuFragment.TAG, menu.itemId)
                else -> false
            }
        }
        selectedItemId = R.id.navigation_menu_main
    }
}

private fun changeFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String, menuId: Int): Boolean {
    supportFragmentManager.commit {
        hide(currentFragment)
        showFragment(fragment, tag)
    }

    currentFragment = fragment
    return true
}

private fun FragmentTransaction.showFragment(fragment: Fragment, tag: String) {
    supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() 
    if (fragment.isAdded) {
        show(fragment)
    } else {
        add(binding.container.id, fragment, tag).show(fragment)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add()` and `replace()` to change fragments in your activity. And the difference between `add` and `replace` is that:

`add` simply add another fragment to the fragment container and does not destroy the existing fragments so they remain active and lifecycle events for those existing fragments are not called.

`replace` removes the existing fragments to add a new fragment which means lifecycle events like onPause, onStop, and onCreateView will be invoked.

Comment: I thought the `onStop` of Fragment is called when it goes behind of other fragment, as if `onStop` is called when Activity go background. And,,, Is it wrong?